# Angular material and ngx infinite scroll

Tags: html, css, angular, angular-material, infinite-scroll

I have a sidebar using angular material and then in the content I have a material table to which I am using ngx-infinite-scroll. If I want that mat-sidenav-container to be full screen I have a position: absolute, but when I am using that the infinite scroll wont work, it wont recognize the scroll. I am stuck here, i have tried to change mat-sidenav-container height but didn't work. Even if I put height: 100vh the scroll wont work. A few thoughts if you have to help me.

Comment: You may try [ngx-ui-scroll](https://github.com/dhilt/ngx-ui-scroll) with "infinite" option set to true. If you'll face any troubles I'll be glad to help you with them.